# How to get boolean value from register_meta properly?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, block-editor

I registered `boolean` by `register_meta()`, to use it in my Gutenberg Plugin Sidebar,
I added default value to it `true`:

```
register_meta( 'post', '_thefuturmeta_post_title_visibility', array(
    'show_in_rest' => [
        'schema' => [
            'type'    => 'boolean',
            'default' => true,
        ]
    ],
    'type' => 'boolean',
    'single' => true,
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
    'auth_callback' => function() {
        return current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
    }
) );
```

So after registering I can see its value in my console, then by my Gutenberg Sidebar I added `ToggleControl` and can change this value, and everything's working perfect.

But I can't get my value properly in my theme:

```
$visibility_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_thefuturmeta_post_title_visibility', true );
var_dump($visibility_title);
```

`var_dump()` will always show `boolean(true)`, if I change default value in get_post_meta to `false` like this:

```
$visibility_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_thefuturmeta_post_title_visibility', false );
```

I will get `bool(false)` even if in my sidebar plugin I have true, but If I switch in my sidebar plugin to false and save and again switch to true, after this `$visibility_title` will be showing always right values depending on `ToggleControl`.

What am I doing wrong? I'm sure I have problem exactly here:

```
$visibility_title = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_thefuturmeta_post_title_visibility', true );
```

But I can't understand what's wrong.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: The third parameter for `get_post_meta()` should be set to `true` -- it specifies whether to get just the first value under the specified `$key` or not. Also, take a look at the the meta value being stored in the database using whatever DB client you prefer. Is the value being stored correctly there?

Comment: @DaveRomsey Yes, I checked in rest api json and my meta value is saved.